# how do i insert the config.php in my phpmyadmin without getting "the page is disabled" error on openshift

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, openshift

I need to add a `config.inc.php` or `config.php` file to my openshift phpmyadmin mysql server , I am getting the page is disabled error:

[image]

Please help me get through and why is this occurring??